# What is the contents of the [[intrinsics]] property in a JavaScript realm?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the contents of the `[[intrinsics]]` property in a JavaScript realm?

I have read some of the spec and cannot fully interpret the description there:

> Record whose field names are intrinsic keys and whose values are
>   objects

Relevant bit of the spec:  https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-code-realms

Edit: are the intrinsic object the built-in objects? Like  Number, Array, etc?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's the built-in constructors, `Math`, etc.

Comment: Look at the "CreateIntrinsics" process (8.2.2). The intrinsics are listed in Table 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[[intrinsics]]` property is defined [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-createintrinsics). It consists of the built-in objects, like `Array`, `Number`, `Math`, `Generator`, `NaN` etc.

It also contains the definitions for `Object.prototype`, `Function.prototype`, a `ThrowTypeError` property (not sure what that is, beyond the superficial interpretation)